# ng-show visible while page loading

Tags: html, angularjs

while page loading message comes and dissappear as active value is false initially. I tried with ng-if, ng-cloak but without success:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="!item.active" class="dialog-expired-calculation alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-cloak>
    <h4 class="redText boldText" translate="parkingPlace.inactive-title"></h4>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
 calculations.forEach(calc => {
        calc.active = version.active;
  });
```

Comment: Is this angular js (v1.x)?

Comment: @Yani yes angular 1.6

Comment: Ok, and are you fetching the data from the server?

Comment: @Yani yes, fetching data from server

Comment: My answer below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using angular 1.x - you can define a `loading` flag and as long as it's true hide/show the part of the screen you want.

Something like this may work -

```
// at the top of the page
$scope.loading = true;

// make your http calls, calculations, etc.
calculations.forEach(calc => {
    calc.active = version.active;
});


// once all http calls and calculations are done
$scope.loading = false;
```

// HTML

```
<div ng-show="!loading && !item.active" class="dialog-expired-calculation alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-cloak><h4 class="redText boldText" translate="parkingPlace.inactive-title"></h4></div>
```

Or you can also use `ng-if` in addition to `ng-show`

```
<div ng-if="!loading" ng-show="!item.active" class="dialog-expired-calculation alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-cloak><h4 class="redText boldText" translate="parkingPlace.inactive-title"></h4></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring it in your init:

```
init() { $scope.item.active = true };
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with below changes as because while page loading before fetching data from controller boolean value set to true and message appears for a while

TS:
calc.active = version.active;
calc['showmessage'] = !version.active;

Html:
ng-show="item.showmessage"

Answer (score -1):

There is no `ng-show` in Angular2+. use ngIf as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="!item.active" class="dialog-expired-calculation alert alert-danger"
 role="alert">
    <h4 class="redText boldText" translate="parkingPlace.inactive-title"></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought you tried using ng-show in angular2. I have updated the tag from angular to angularjs so it reaches the right audience.